# pin in data - stack size error

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I'm trying to put a "pin in data" label in my figure (an osciloscope capture) but I get this error message

```
tex capacity exceeded sorry [input stack size=5000]
```

This is my MWE that compiles properly when removing the pin-in-data line indicated in the comment.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

        \usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

        \tikzset{
        %define custom "osciloscope axis"
        data visualization/our system/.style={
        new Cartesian axis=horizontal axis,
        new Cartesian axis=vertical axis,
        %
        horizontal axis={unit vector={(1pt,0 cm)},length=6 cm},
        vertical axis={unit vector={(0cm,1pt)},length=5 cm},
        %
        horizontal axis ={attribute=xpos, min value=-5, max value=5},
        vertical axis ={attribute=ypos, min value=-4, max value=4},
        %
        horizontal axis= {visualize axis={vertical axis={goto=max},low=-5,high=5},
                        visualize axis={vertical axis={goto pos=0.5},low=-5,high=5},
                        visualize axis={vertical axis={goto=min},low=-5,high=5},
                        ticks={step=1, minor steps between steps=4}},
        vertical axis= {visualize axis={horizontal axis={goto=min},low=-4,high=4},
                      visualize axis={horizontal axis={goto pos=0.5},low=-4,high=4},
                      visualize axis={horizontal axis={goto=max},low=-4,high=4},
                      ticks={step=1, minor steps between steps=4}},
        %
        all axes={grid={some}},
        vertical axis={visualize grid={direction axis=horizontal axis, common={style={black!90,dotted}}},
                    visualize ticks={direction axis=horizontal axis,low=-2,high=2pt,horizontal axis={goto=0}}},
        horizontal axis={visualize grid={direction axis=vertical axis, common={style={black!90,dotted}}},
                    visualize ticks={direction axis=vertical axis,low=-2,high=2pt,vertical axis={goto=0}}}
        }
        }

        \tikz \datavisualization [
        our system,
        all axes={grid=many},
        visualize as line=signal,
        %signal={pin in data={text=$My labels$,index=1,pin length= 5 ex, pin angle= 45}}, % this is the line that doesn't work
        style sheet= vary hue,% label in data
        ]
        data [set=signal] {
        xpos, ypos
        -4.966, 3.044
        4.946, 2.811
        };

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you for helping, any advive would be apreciated!

Diego

Answer (score 1):

I've just happened to discover what is wrong, but still don't know why it is wrong.

the line

```
    \tikz \datavisualization [
```

should be replaced by

```
    \datavisualization [
```

Could anyone explain or give a hint of the differences between them?

Comment: `\tikz ...` is a short form for `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}`, so you're trying to start a new `tikzpicture` inside the existing one, causing trouble.